# Ampere's Force Law question on units

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

I have a question on units using this law.  It's my understanding Ampere's Force Law follows from the Biot-Savart Law and Lorentz Force Law:
$$
\vec B (\vec r) = \frac {\mu_0} {4 \pi} \int_C \frac {I d\vec l \times \hat r'} {|\vec r'|^2} = \frac {\mu_0} {4 \pi} \int_C \frac {I d\vec l \times \vec r'} {|\vec r'|^3}
$$
where the units should be:
$$
\vec B(\vec r) = \frac N {m A}
$$

**Question**: the above RHS (without the unit vector $\hat r'$) has the correct units but the middle equation is $\frac N A$.  Have I interpreted something incorrectly leading to this?

Comment: The middle and right have the same units. I'm not following here.

Comment: What are you saying $\hat r'$ is? It should be unitless, since $\hat r'=\vec r'/|\vec r'|$

Comment: You are confused about something. This is not Ampere's force law and has nothing to do with force. It is just Ampere's law, it produces the vector magnetic induction (B) for a distribution of currents. The unit for B is tesla. You can write the tesla as N/(m*A) but what is the point? The actual Ampere's force law describes the force between two current carrying wires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\hat{r}’$ is a unit vector with a magnitude of 1. As such, it is dimensionless.  One way to see this is that we can create a unit vector out of any vector by dividing it by its own magnitude:  $\hat{A} = \vec{A}/|\vec{A}|$.  But $\vec{A}$ and $|\vec{A}|$ have the same units, and so $\hat{A}$ is dimensionless.

Once you realize this, it is not hard to see that the units of the second and third integrals are identical.

Comment: Why is the unit vector dimensionless?

Comment: @Nick:  See my edit.

Comment: Very clear, thanks!